# Datatables French Language issue

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables 1.10.19

I want to localize (internationalize) the table controls.

```
var table = $('#table_id').DataTable({
    language: {
        url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/French.json"
    }
});
```

The table controls are displayed in English and not French.

When I use `url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/German.json"`, the table controls are localized in German language.

Then why is French not working?

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it like this it's working for me :

```
"language": {
                "sEmptyTable":     "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
                "sInfo":           "Affichage de l'élément _START_ à _END_ sur _TOTAL_ éléments",
                "sInfoEmpty":      "Affichage de l'élément 0 à 0 sur 0 élément",
                "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtré à partir de _MAX_ éléments au total)",
                "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                "sLengthMenu":     "Afficher _MENU_ éléments",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement...",
                "sProcessing":     "Traitement...",
                "sSearch":         "Rechercher :",
                "sZeroRecords":    "Aucun élément correspondant trouvé",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sFirst":    "Premier",
                    "sLast":     "Dernier",
                    "sNext":     "Suivant",
                    "sPrevious": "Précédent"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending":  ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
                    "sSortDescending": ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
                },
                "select": {
                    "rows": {
                        "_": "%d lignes sélectionnées",
                        "0": "Aucune ligne sélectionnée",
                        "1": "1 ligne sélectionnée"
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

I know the issue is old but in case someone else is still looking for a French translation CDN plugin, this is where to find it : https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/French

Answer (score 0):

When looking at 
       https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/French.json vs 
        https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/German.json

I would say the French.json is missing some translations. Especially the buttons: {} is missing. If you are French you can make a PR to add the missing Stuff https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/pulls.